# Resize image before it is loaded but after DOM is

Tags: jquery, html, css, tumblr

I have a high-res images that I am loading into a page. They're all set to render small by default (max-width of 500px in this case), but if the image is wider than it is tall I want to render it larger with a max-width of 900px. I want to do this with a script (I'm using jQuery) because I don't know what the image sizes are beforehand and can't hard-code in their max-widths. I am using max-width instead of width because I don't want to overstretch images that are less than 900px.

In doing this, I want to set the image size before the image is loaded (so it doesn't flash in its original size then to the new size, moving all the elements in the page around in the process), but after DOM is created (so I can access their naturalHeight and naturalWidth).

This is what I tried:

```
<style>
img.portfolio {
  max-width: 500px;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.portfolio").each(function(){ 
        if ($(this)[0].naturalHeight < $(this)[0].naturalWidth) {
          var ratio = $(this)[0].naturalHeight / $(this)[0].naturalWidth;
          $(this).css("max-width", 900);
          $(this).css("max-height", 900*ratio);
          $(this).width($(this)[0].naturalwidth);
          $(this).width($(this)[0].naturalheight);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

But I find that this only works sometimes! It seems to work all the time in Chrome, but I noticed the first time I load the page in Firefox it won't work and all images have a width of 500px, but subsequent page reloads it will work. I loaded the page in Firefox with cache off and it didn't work. Why is this the case? How do I fix it? And why is this a problem in Firefox but not Chrome?

---

**EDIT** Additional mystery: I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25jbo1k9/5/) for the question, and I couldn't actually reproduce the bug in the fiddle in Firefox. What! So I made an example on a tumblr, which is what I'm trying to get this script to work with. It is [here](http://25jbo1k9.tumblr.com/), and it randomly sometimes works and doesn't work in both Firefox and Chrome when I have browser cache off. What's happening? I suspect this has to do with how tumblr renders its templates; how do I circumvent this irregularity?

Answer (score 0):

change max-with to width

```
  $(this).css("maxWidth", 900);
  $(this).css("maxHeight", 900*ratio);
```

Comment: This would work if I knew for sure the images would be at least 900px width or height, but they can be any width or height, and I don't want to stretch out the image, which is why I used max-width and max-height.

Comment: jQuery wants css elements to be strings, so I tried your answer except with quotes: 
$(this).css("maxWidth", 900); 
 $(this).css("maxHeight", 900*ratio);
had the same problem though ):

Comment: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/resizable-maxwidth-and-maxheight-options-vs-css-maxwidth-and-maxheight

Comment: This is a discussion about resizeable in jQueryUI (http://jqueryui.com/resizable/). I don't want my images to be resizeable, I want to set their size as they load.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply insert the image hidden (display: none), resize it while hidden and only then make it visible.

Comment: That would fix the weird flashing from one size to another problem, but I still need to address the not working in Firefox problem.